# epoll ET, what events should I subscribe to on listening socket?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, epoll, berkeley-sockets

I have a fd:

```
socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, ...)
bind(fd, ...)
listen(fd, ...)
```

And I have a `epoll` instance. I need to know, what events should I subscribe to via `epoll_ctl`? I need Edge Triggered mode.

I have those flags atm: `EPOLLET | EPOLLIN`

Should I subscribe to `EPOLLRDHUP`, `EPOLLOUT`, `EPOLLPRI` ?

Should I handle `EPOLLHUP`, `EPOLLERR` ? Why they can occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask specifically about the passive socket used to  accept  incoming  connection
       requests. The example in [man epoll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) doesn't subscribe to `EPOLLRDHUP`, `EPOLLOUT`, `EPOLLPRI` for the listening socket, and understandably so:

- `EPOLLOUT` means: *Writing now will not block.* - There is no writing on the passive socket.
- `EPOLLRDHUP` applies to connections. There isn't a connection on the passive socket.
- `EPOLLPRI` means: *There is urgent data to read*. There's no urgent data on a passive socket.

Also the example doesn't handle `EPOLLHUP`, `EPOLLERR` for the listening socket. That's at least understandable for `EPOLLHUP`, since that applies to *output only*. I know of no case where `EPOLLERR` would be returned for the passive socket.